# Веселая смена фона вместе с Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Значит суть в следующем:

 Создается новый компонент, который рисует треугольник:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Random;

public class Triangle extends Component {

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Random rn = new Random();
    Color c = new Color(rn.nextInt(256), rn.nextInt(256), rn.nextInt(256));
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; // холст для рисования

    int nPoints = 3;
    int[] xPoints = new int[nPoints + 1];
    int[] yPoints = new int[nPoints + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) {
        double angle = 2 * Math.PI * i / nPoints;
        xPoints[i] = (int) (150 + 175 * Math.sin(angle));
        yPoints[i] = (int) (100 - 100 * Math.cos(angle));
    }
    g2d.setColor(c);        
    g2d.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
    //repaint(); //если раскомментировать - треугольник неистово мигает в основном окне.
}
}
```

Треугольник создается и добавляется на панель окна по нажатию кнопки:

```
Triangle t = new Triangle();
    t.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    t.setLocation(new Point((jPanel1.getWidth() - 260) / 2, (jPanel1.getHeight() - 200) / 2));
    t.setVisible(true);
    jPanel1.add(t);
```

А другой кнопочкой меняется background панели:

```
Random rn = new Random();
Color c2 = new Color(rn.nextInt(256), rn.nextInt(256), rn.nextInt(256));
jPanel1.setBackground(c2);
```

И происходит следующее:

При нажатии на кнопку рисования треугольника - треугольник рисуется, при нажатии еще раз - меняет фон (по сути рисуется заново, новый объект жи создаем, а там background рандомный). 

 При нажатии на смену фона панели - меняется цвет фона и панели и... треугольника (sic). 

Под отладчиком видно, что заново вызывается метод *paint*.

Вопросы: <s>какого хера?</s> Почему так происходит? Нормально ли это? Как это исправить?

Comment: Разве paint не вызывается при каждой перерисовке объекта?

Comment: это нормально. `paint` вызывается каждый раз, когда надо нарисовать объект. Когда вы меняете фон, надо перерисовать всю панель, и все ее дочерние компоненты (треугольник). Поскольку цвет вы выбираете в `paint`, то он меняется. Вынесите цвет и координаты вершин в поля класса, и задавайте в конструкторе.

Comment: @zRrr спасибо! Можете оформить это в ответ, все заработало.